# Self-signed docker registry in CircleCI

Tags: docker, docker-registry, circleci, self-signed, circleci-2.0

I'm using CircleCI 2.0 and I have a private docker registry with self-signed certificate. I'm able to configure my local docker, just like [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#use-self-signed-certificates), the problem is in CircleCI:

I'm using remote dockers so when I try to login in Docker registry it's failing with `Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry.mycompany.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

Is there a way to install the certificate in a remote docker? I don't have access to the docker host's shell. I don't want to use machine executor type.

Comment: Have you changed `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`? It was set to something like `/tmp/docker-certs123456789/` in order to connect to its default remote Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. It could only be accomplished by using CircleCI's Enterprise level system.